# how to use powershell script to say IF users in direct reports are enabled do

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script on the server at work that works good but I need to add an if cast into it.
This script checks all those users that are in "Direct reports" if they are about to expire send mail to their manager.
Question: I want to explain in my PowerShell that IF users are disabled do not send an email and IF users indirect reports are enabled send mail or continue the rest of the script. I don't know how to write like this in PowerShell format :(
I attach a part of my script here...

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If users in  $_.directReports are enabled  send email to manager otherwise don't send email to manager.....It is abit complicated , right ??? :(

Comment: add `-and ($userDetails.enabled -eq $true)` to `if $userdetails.accountexpirationdate`
Really hard to see your code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following within your code:

```
$TargetExpirationDate = Get-Date -Year 2019 -Month 01 -Day 31
$_.DirectReports | Foreach-Object {
    $userDetails = Get-Aduser -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$_' -and AccountExpirationDate -le '$TargetExpirationDate' -and Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties AccountExpirationDate,EmailAddress
    # Other code
}
```

Set `$TargetExpirationDate` to be the expiration date to check against. The code will identify enabled users who have an expiration date ***on or before*** `$TargetExpirationDate`. `$userDetails` will contain just one single user at a time. You can make `$userDetails` contain all users that meet the criteria by doing the following:

```
$TargetExpirationDate = Get-Date -Year 2019 -Month 01 -Day 31
$userDetails = $_.DirectReports | Foreach-Object {
    Get-Aduser -Filter "DistinguishedName -eq '$_' -and AccountExpirationDate -le '$TargetExpirationDate' -and Enabled -eq '$true'" -Properties AccountExpirationDate,EmailAddress
    # Other code
}
```